# Sketch $\{z^2|\text{Re}(z)>0\}$. Having troubles with finding what points are or aren't in the graph.

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers

Sketch $\{z^2|\text{Re}(z)>0\}=\{(x^2-y^2,2xy)|x>0\}$. Let $(a,b)$ be any point in $\Bbb{R}^2$. I want to see what kind of restrictions I get on this point. 
$$a=x^2-y^2,b=2xy\Rightarrow x={b\over2y}\Rightarrow a={b^2\over 4y^2}-y^2$$ 
Denoting $y^2=t$, $$t^2+4at-b^2=0$$
Now I am getting all sorts or expressions too hard to actually put on a sketch. Like $y=\pm \sqrt{2a+\sqrt{4a^2+b^2}}$. How can I do it right? I would appreciate your help.

Comment: You are attempting to plot 4-dimensional data since $z=x+iy$ (two dimensions), and $z^2=u+iv$ (a further two dimensions). One way to plot this is using a vector field, but that's probably not what you're after. Another way would be to plot $|z^2|$ in a three-dimensional space. Also, you say your expressions are too hard - maybe you will need to numerically evaluate your expressions.

Comment: I am pretty sure I am to look at it as a mere complex number, where its real part will be represented by the x axis and the imaginary part by the y axis. The question stated "in the complex plane" and there was only one lecture, so I guess it should be 2-D.

Comment: @pbs he is meant to sketch a subset of $\Bbb C$; that's "two-dimensional" data.

Comment: So what you actually want to do is plot the image of the function, i.e. the codomain.

Comment: @pbs yes, he is sketching the image.  No, that is not what "codomain" means.

Comment: @pbs the asker was quite clear about what he was meant to do. It's you who decided that he's trying to graph a function over $\Bbb C$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I'd not considered the image/codomain difference before, so thanks for your comment. However, it was not clear to me. The OP mentions graph in the title which means to me the set of ordered pairs $(z,z^2)$, both elements being complex numbers. But yes, the sketching statement clears that up. Apologies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a lot easier if you write $z$ in polar form: $z = re^{i\theta}$ with $-\pi < \theta \le \pi$ and $r \ge 0$. Then $\operatorname{Re}(z) > 0$ if and only if $-\frac\pi2 < \theta < \frac\pi2$ and $r > 0$.

Thus, $z^2 = r^2 e^{2i\theta} = se^{i\phi}$ with $s=r^2 > 0$ and $-\pi < \phi <\pi$. Which complex numbers can be written in this way? (Answer: every complex number except...)

Comment: I put no faith in the polar representations, but it is now restored. Thank you, I shall try it right away and feedback you.

Comment: @Meitar as a general rule, polar representations are particularly useful whenever there is more multiplication than addition.

Comment: How can I claim equivalence between $[-\pi,\pi]$ and $[0,2\pi]$ elegantly? I think it would make things easier.

Comment: @Meitar I'm not sure exactly what you mean, but I assume that you are familiar with polar representation of complex numbers? Every complex number can be written as $re^{i\theta}$, where $r\ge 0$ is uniquely determined, but the argument $\theta$ is only determined up to a multiple of $2\pi$. To get a unique choice of $\theta$, the easiest is to restrict to a (half-open) interval of length $2\pi$, for example $(-\pi,\pi]$ or $[0,2\pi)$. Other choices are also possible.